# SQL - Call a series of functions dynamically using meta data

Tags: sql, function, dynamic, azure-sql-database

I'm looking to build a cleansing process in SQL. The idea is to define a series of core functions (e.g. remove whitespace, remove symbols, remove numbers). Then have a meta data table which stores each column name in the solution, the function(s) to run on that column and the order.
Then to simply pass in each column, it looks up the meta data and runs each function in the correct order, returning the final value.

I had intended to use a 'control function' to do this. Pass in the column name and value as parameters, it then loops through each function in turn, passing the value between them and ultimately returning the final value back to the original SELECT statement.

But I have discovered you can't alter the DB in a function, and so you can't use dynamic SQL, so you can't dynamically pass in the function name within the control function.

The idea had been something like this - pseudo code which would be part of a loop. But essentially  it would iterate over all the identified functions for that column (contiained in 'functions_to_run') and update the @value accordingly

```
SET @function = (SELECT [function] FROM #functions_to_run WHERE [function_order] = @current_function)

@SQL = 'SET @value = SELECT @function (@value)

SET @current_function += 1

loop, loop, loop

return @value'
```

Without being able to use dynamic SQL in a function, I think this idea is entirely out? There seems to be no way to orchestrate a series of functions from within one master function?

---

The next idea was to orchestrate the dynamic element within the stored procedure, which would loop through the columns and identify the functions to run. There I can use dynamic SQL to call each function in turn and return the value. But here I would need to make the entire SQL statement dynamic (so that we SELECT the correct column and insert it into the correct column)
E.g.

```
Create #list_of_columns with all columns in the table and a row_id to iterate over

SET @SQL = 'DECLARE @field_name VARCHAR (100) = (SELECT [column] FROM #list_of_columns WHERE [row_number = @current_column
            DECLARE @value VARCHAR (100)

            BEGIN LOOP of functions on column
            SET @value = (SELECT @function (@value)

            Loop, loop, loop

            SELECT @value AS @field_name

            Then loop onto next column'
```

This should be possible. We have a list of column names in a table any way (or can use the schema tables). We can take each column name in a loop, create the same temp table of the functions to run and iterate over that and call the above code, passing in the new @field_value each time and then finally write it to the correct field name in the target table.

The problem is that this is quite a bit of dynamic code. And I'm not sure it is worth the hassle compared to just hardcoding the function calls for each attribute - plus the reduced need to maintain a meta data table. I'm also not sure that I'll get approval for making it this dynamic (versus using a tool to do it in a more 'structured' way)

So my two questions are:

- Can you orchestrate the calling of functions dynamically within another function?
- Is there a simpler/better way to form the stored procedure and iterate over each column in a table, iterating over a dynamic set of functions for each column? I also wonder if you can even iterate over the columns in that way - I suspect the end SELECT statement won't work as expected (I think maybe an UPDATE and SET might work better to input the final value)

Or is my second option the best design for this there is?

Comment: so why can't your "control function" be a stored procedure?

Comment: I think I can. that's the second option detailed above. Though I think it isn't as straightforward as the final SELECT statement for each column - I think won't work in a loop. Instead I think the final statement has to be an UPDATE to SET the final value in the table using unique record keys

However, I don't think I'll get approval for making it this dynamic (there are other, less 'coded' solutions that would likely be preferred by the business). 

So my question is whether the second option is the correct way to design a control procedure. Or if I'm missing a better way to do it.